# What is to be used in PDW inplace of identity

Tags: parallel-data-warehouse

What is to be used in PDW inplace of identity or is there any other column which can be used instead of Identity column in Parallel Datawarehousing or any alternative how to generate sequentially increasing column.

Comment: why does it have to be sequential increasing and not guid

Comment: Because guids aren't supported.

Answer (score 2):

Try using `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) + (SELECT MAX(ID) FROM dbo.TheTable)`